# iOS 8, uploading multi files into AWS S3 Bucket, while app running in the backgroud

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to AWS S3, working on app that will have a large number of files ( probably hundreds of 1 mb files ). Because of the large size I want to be able to perform this upload while app is in background mode. I went through the AWS documentation for http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html
But this does not talk about whether its possible for it to run while app is in background. This app is kind of like a dropbox for photos. 
to clarify more, I am using iOS 8, as per this page

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

`AWSS3TrasnferManager` does not support background transfer. You should use `AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder` instead. You should take a look at [S3BackgroundTransfer-Sample](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples) that demonstrates how to use background transfer with `AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder`.

Comment: Hi Yosuke, so I looked at the other sample and its very interesting. I am basically trying to do what the S3TransferManager-Sample project is, but using the S3BackgroundTransfer-Sample idea, do you envision any issues with that? I have a UICollectionview of pics ( just like S3TransferManager-Sample project) and I want to upload them to S3, now if the app is running in the foreground or background I want the upload to work till its done , and all in the background. So can that be done using preseignedURL, and NSURLSession?

Answer (score 0):

For those who still see this question, you can check out my tutorial on uploading large file to S3 using multipart in the background. You should be able to extrapolate how to do it for non multipart upload: 
[Taming the AWS framework to upload a large file to S3](http://www.mobdesignapps.fr/blog/2016/10/26/uploading-large-file-to-aws-s3-in-the-background?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=response&utm_campaign=awareness&utm_term=28312758)